# laravel database query not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query as following:

```
$this->_data['news'] = PageContent::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('category_id', 3)->where('status', 1)->first();
```

And in my index.blade.php file, data is displayed in such manner:

```
@if(count($news) > 0)
    <div class="post_list_content_unit col-sm-6">
        <div class="feature-image">
            <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/about-us/news-event" class="entry-thumbnail">
                <img width="370" height="260"
                     src="{{URL::to('Uploads/pageContents/'.$news->image)}}"
                     alt="{{$news->title}}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-list-content">
            <div class="post_list_inner_content_unit">
                <h3 class="post_list_title">
                    <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/about-us/news-event"
                       rel="bookmark">{{$news->title}}</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="post_list_item_excerpt">
                    {!! str_limit($news->description, 300) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <div></div>
@endif
```

But instead of showing records with only status=1, it is displaying data with status value 0 also.

Is there something wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array to the `where` method:

```
$this->_data['news'] = PageContent::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->where(array('category_id'=>3,'status'=>1))
->first();
```

Comment: Indeed, I find this way a bit flexible if you do not know the exact number of filters though

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways by passing array in where clause:

```
$this->_data['news']  = DB::table('PageContent')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where([
        ['category_id', '=', '3'],
        ['status', '=', '1'],
      ])->first();
```

Or by

```
$this->_data['news']  = PageContent::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where([
        ['category_id', '=', '3'],
        ['status', '=', '1'],
      ])->first();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this :

```
$this->_data['news'] = PageContent::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->where(function($query) {
              $query->where('category_id', 3)
              $query->where('status', 1);
            })
            ->first();
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: But I don't want to display records that are disabled... this query doesn't work for that , I guess.

Comment: that will fetch records with 0 status value too... not working